# How to use Grails belongsTo in Java

Tags: java, grails, belongs-to

I have this situation in grails

```
static belongsTo = [owner: Publisher]
```

How can I convert this in java?

Comment: how can I convert it to turbo-basic?

Comment: I prefer turbo pascal myself. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is `You can not` convert it to java.

The longer answer, and reason why, is because that static property is used by Grails to enhance your class with additional methods and functionality using Groovy meta programming. This type of meta programming isn't available in Java and one of the primary reasons why Groovy is used in this case.

Without knowing **why** you want to do so it's impossible to suggest any alternative approach.

Comment: In this case, I replaced it with a simple pointer to class. Thanks for the explenation